# how can i get the data from this array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, array-push

I have the following code..

```
$array_test = array();

for($i = 0;$i<5;$i++) {
    array_push($array_test,array("result".$i=>"exist_data".$i));
}

for($j = 0; $j<count($array_test);$j++) {
    echo $array_test[$j];
}

var_dump($array_test); // the data exist
```

but the loop for only show me `ArrayArrayArrayArray`

thanks for help.

Comment: Try to access `$array_test[$j]["result".$j];`

Comment: you push an array to arry_test and when you try to print it shows an array. Thats correct . is it ? instead of echo try print_r(array_test[$j]) .

Comment: yh thats work, thanks all for answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $array_test[$j];` would not work because you have a **2D** array and can't access the variables of 2D array in that way. This would throw **Array to String Conversion** error.

Change your code to :-

```
for($j = 0; $j<count($array_test);$j++) {
    echo $array_test[$j]["result".$j] ."<br>";
}
```

**Output**

```
exist_data0
exist_data1
exist_data2
exist_data3
exist_data4
```